# How to insert new row in Ultragrid

Tags: vb6, ultrawingrid

it is  very difficult to find any answer on Ultragrid ..

I have a small issue and could not solve it.

1. how to insert new row when click on add button...if any previous row is there has to clea out and add only 1 new row.. how to delete row on click of delete button (i tried using deleteselectrow..but need to select row first..what if only 1 row is present then need to directly delete present row)
2. I am using VB6 with MS Access as backend database. The recordset is bounded to
   database throughï Infragistics ultragrid. (Set ultraGrid.DataSource = rs)

I have 3 columns in Infragistics ultragrid & 3 Textboxes on form.

Now, when I move through the records in ultraGrid the exact data in the cells should appear in the related textboxes.

in msflex i think we do with

```
Text1.Text = MSHFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(MSHFlexGrid1.Row,1)
```

How to get this job done in ultragrid?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only bit of code I could find as far as adding new rows to an Ultragrid:

```
grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].AddNew();
```

This forum post - [How to add rows in UltraGrid?](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/15087/55297.aspx) - may offer some help.  I wouldn't think the process would be all that different.